# PHP string to XML file

Tags: php, xml

In PHP, i have a `$string` that contains XML-structured data.

How can i create and save a XML file from `$string`?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can use:

```
file_put_contents("myxmlfile.xml", $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use DOM to load the XML string
http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php

and then use DOM to save the XML to file
http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) for example

Answer (score 0):

For just storing the XML to a file, go with Teneff's answer.

But if you also want to parse the XML, use `SimpleXML` (or even better: `XMLReader` / `XMLWriter`).

Of course, you could also use `DOM`, but out of all the possibilities around, this would be the slowest and most memory consuming one.